# xelatex compilation of pstricks fails

Tags: xetex, pstricks

I just needed to compile the following lines (minimal example)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\listfiles
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
Ein
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-3)(5,8)
\psline(0,1)(2,3)
\end{pspicture}
Test
\end{document}
```

But that went wrong. I'm sorry - but I can only ask for help here - because I'm not able to see any problem in there.
As `tug.org/PSTricks` reads, it should work fine directly with XeLaTeX.
I'm using TexLive2010.
For further description, here is the output of `xelatex test | grep pstricks`

```
(/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.st
(/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.
(/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.te
(/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pst
(/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xd
(/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pst
(/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xd
(/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.te
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--
Operand stack:
   (/home/ebeling/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   1877   1   3   %oparray_pop   1861   1   3   %oparray_pop   1755   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1878   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1161/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:70/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 82
GPL Ghostscript 8.71: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

** WARNING ** Filtering file via command -->ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode '/tmp/dvipdfmx.XXSJ7G06' '/tmp/dvipdfmx.XXaj80iD'<-- failed.
** WARNING ** Image format conversion for PSTricks failed.
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command pst: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(160.635, 85.5393)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "pst:  tx@Dict begin STP newpath /ArrowA { moveto } def /ArrowB "
pstricks.sty    2010/09/18 v0.48 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2011/01/30 v2.17 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
```

The other lines do not show up more details.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: I just tried to compile with `xelatex -no-pdf` and that worked fine. Convert via `xdvipdfmx` throws the same error lines.

Comment: Hmmm, seems to work fine for me.  I'm using TL2010 on Linux with GhostScript 8.71.  My log file contains the line 'Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx'.

Comment: @Andrew: did you run `tlmgr --self --all update` before?

Comment: @Herbert: No, I didn't.  I presume from your comment that this would that have introduced the problem.  That's useful to know for the context of the error.

Comment: @Bastian: It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Sorry! I just wanted to be polite - and thus I began with a greeting formula.

Comment: @Bastian: There's nothing to be sorry about. If anyone could be sorry, then it should be me for removing your politeness. Having a greeting or a closing is just "nicht üblich" here. (By the way, you expressed your politeness in a great way by accepting Ulrike's answer and by leaving a comment.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Edit 2023

This answer is old and quite certainly no long valid (unless you want to correct a 13 years old texlive 2010). If you have in a current system problems with xelatex and pstricks better ask a new question with a new minimal example.

### Old Answer

Herbert Voss wrote in an answer to a similar question in c.t.t.:

edit the file .../texlive/2010/texmf/dvipdfmx/dvipdfmx.cfg
to insert the option -dNOSAFER into the line with ps2pdf

```
D  "ps2pdf -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dNOSAFER -sPAPERSIZE=a0 ...
```

without -dNOSAFER ghostscript can't run external files

Comment: I have tried this in MikteX, but with no success. The file is at C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\dvipdfm\config\dvipdfmx.cfg, and the invocation seems to be for "mgs.exe", or "MikteX's gs". I inserted -dNOSAFER, saved, but saw no difference. Maybe that isn't the right file, or there is some other refresh operation that must take place, because commenting out the entire line also made no difference.