# xelatex and pstricks

Tags: xetex, pstricks, windows, texworks

I am using miktex 2.9 with texworks & windows 7 ultimate SP1 to compile my code. I am compiling using xelatex however, my code is not compiling. What should I do ? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,0)(2.5,1)
\psdots(0,0)(2,0)(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is [this](http://spandex.io/p/51345d907e95484f5200a5f0) what you were expecting ? can you post the errors inside `your-filename.log` here to diagnose  the problem.

Comment: I don't have any problems with the same system. Do you have all the required packages installed?

Comment: It compiles fine on Fedora 18 with TeX Live 2012 (and Emacs + AUCTeX) too.

Comment: I am sorry to be rude or anything but I have never used linux or linux based systems in my life. I tried to use ubuntu but it has quite a steep learning curve so I am not going to bother to learn it. In total, I do not want any sort of linux-based solution so please could you all refrain from posting such solutions. Thanks. Also, I have re-installed miktex and this time only downloading & installing basic miktex. The issue has been resolved but I ran into what it looks like is a bug.

Comment: Whenever I download & install basic miktex and compile pstricks code everything works. Graphics is displayed perfectly. However, when I go into package manager and install all packages and then refresh FNDB and update format in Settings, all of a sudden I cannot compile my pstricks code and the graphics ceases to be displayed. I know there is something wrong but I am not a programmer and do I have any experience with tex programming whatsoever.

Comment: @user5976 No one is suggesting/forcing you to use Linux. You have all freedom to do what you like. They are posting to verify the code works on all platforms to confirm its compilation. Remember LaTeX code should work on [all platforms](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94297/15717). you should have posted `your-filename.log` the error/bug screenshots instead of "I ran into what it looks like is a bug." and "my code is not compiling". Please help us to help you.

Comment: Possibly [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13359/14100) will help you.

Comment: Okay, I have installed the complete miktex system with miktex net installer 32 bit. I still have the same error. How do I attach files here ? I cannot post the error log because it is too long and I see no button for attaching documents.

Comment: Any ideas what to do next ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem which is not reproducible with an up-to-date TeX system.


Comment: As others have said, this issue is not reproducible, so without the log file it's essentially not answerable.