# Problem with pspicture inside a poster

Tags: posters, pspicture

I have a trouble to add a pspicture into a poster:

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}


\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt 
\columnseprule=3pt 


\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{figures/}} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.75\linewidth}
\veryHuge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Unnecessarily Complicated Research Title} \color{Black}\\ % Title
\Huge\textit{An Exploration of Complexity}\\[2cm] % Subtitle
\huge \textbf{John Smith \& James Smith}\\[0.5cm] % Author(s)
\huge University and Department Name\\[0.4cm] % University/organization
\Large \texttt{john@LaTeXTemplates.com} --- 1 (000) 111 1111\\
\end{minipage}
%


\vspace{1cm} % A bit of extra whitespace between the header and poster content

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{multicols}{3} % This is how many columns your poster will be broken into, a portrait poster is generally split into 2 columns

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   ABSTRACT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{pspicture}(0,-1.5002344)(13.1892185,1.5002344)
\rput(0,0){
\rput(-5,0){
%\pscircle[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](4.3992186,0.058886718){0.8}
\pscircle[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](7.8992186,0.058886718){0.8}
%\pscircle[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](11.399219,0.058886718){0.8}
%\rput[bl](3.1492188,1.1588867){Core $(m-1)$ - th}
\rput[bl](7.099219,1.2588867){Core $m$ - th}
%\rput[bl](10.129219,1.1588867){Core $(m+1)$ - th}
%\rput[bl](4.3992186,0.058886718){$n_0$}
\rput[bl](6.0492187,0.058886718){$n_0$}
\rput[bl](7.8992186,0.058886718){$n_{g_m}$}
\rput[bl](9.549219,0.058886718){$n_0$}
%\rput[bl](11.399219,0.058886718){$n_0$}
}
\rput(-3,-1.5){
\psaxes[linecolor=gray,labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(0,0)        (1,1)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\pscircle[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, dimen=outer](0.7,0.7){0.2}
\psdots[linecolor=black, dotsize=0.07](0.7,0.7)
\rput[bl](1,0.7){$z$}
}
}   
\end{pspicture}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the pspicture doesn't appear.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> It's more a comment than an answer.

I get the following output.

[image]

I used `tex --> dvi --> PS --> PDF`.

Comment: I dont get the circle and the axis $x,y,z$ also. I compile with xelatex is that the problem ?

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis I do not know that, see here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13359 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204269.

Comment: I have compile my report with xelatex and there is no problem and i used a lot of times the pspicture enviroment there was no problem.

Comment: So when i tried to copy pspictures from my report to poster i have problems

Comment: @chaviarasmichalis Maybe -- as a workaround -- you can generate a separate file for every picture and include it in the poster as an image.

Comment: Ok thanks , but do you know if it is hard to set the tex enable to texmaker ? I have only latex, pdflatex,xelatex .... no plain tex

Comment: Use `LaTeX` - I also used this. With `tex` I meant the `.tex` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60603/discussion-between-chaviaras-michalis-and-dr-manuel-kuehner).